# What is difference between primary key and identity?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

What is its use, when both **identifies** the **unique** row?
 Why people are using identity column as a **primary** key ?
 Can anyone briefly describe the answer ?

Comment: An identity is a type of a primary key defined by the RDBMS you are using

Comment: You need to specify what exactly RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primary key is a logical concept - it is the means by which you will uniquely identify each record in a table. There are several types of primary key - a natural key uses a data attribute from the business domain which is guaranteed to have the requirements for a primary key (unique, not null, immutability) such as a social security number, a compound key is a key made up of multiple columns (often used in "parent-child" relationships), and a surrogate key is created by the system; it could be an auto-increment, or identity column.

Identity is a data type. It is very useful for use as a surrogate primary key, because it has all the attributes required. It's unlikely you'd use the identity type for purposes other than as a primary key, but there's nothing to stop you from doing so.

So, not all primary keys use the identity data type, and not all identity columns are primary keys.

Comment: IDENTITY is not a data type but a property.
reference: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/what-is-the-use-of-identity-data-type,
also see [identity property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3):

**Primary key** is a kind of **unique key**. It's, in fact, a restriction (constraint) that values for a specific column (or, in general case, set of columns) cannot be the same in different rows (even when manually/explicitly setting to same values with an insert/update).

Primary/unique key isn't required to be an auto-incremented. It's, in fact, isn't required to be integer at all — it can be text or other type.

Primary key is a bit stricter than usual unique key in that it usually implies `NOT NULL` and, in additional to that, only one primary key is allowed per table (while several unique keys per table are allowed in addition to primary key).

Creating primary/unique key usually implicitly creates an index to make search and constraint-checking by that column(s) faster.

E.g. if column `my_column` of `my_table` is marked as primary or unique key, you can't do this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column, other_column, third_column)
    VALUES (10, …, …);
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column, other_column, third_column)
    VALUES (10, …, …);  -- the same value for my_column again
```

**Identity** in your RDBMS is what other RDBMSes may call *auto_increment* or *serial*. It's just a feature that during an row-insert operation a specific column, when not being explicitly set to some value, is automatically initialized to (most often) consecutive integer values.

E.g. if column `my_column` of `my_table` is marked as auto_increment/serial/identity, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (other_column, third_column) VALUES (…, …);
    -- not specifying any value for my_column manually,
    -- it'll be initialized automatically to some value
    -- (usually an increasing integer sequence)
```

Auto_increment/serial/identity usually doesn't guarantee *strict* consequentiality of automatic values (especially in case of aborted transactions).

Concretely [documentation for TRANSACT-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) says that identity doesn't guarantee:

- uniqueness (use unique/primary keys to enforce that);
- strict consequentiality.

**Update:** As [a_horse_with_no_name suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296403/1421194#comment71753138_42296403), "identity" appears to be not only a name of the common auto_increment/serial/identity feature within specific RDBMSes (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server), but also a name defined by ANSI SQL standard.

AFAIK, it doesn't differ *very much* from what I described above (about the common auto_increment/serial/identity feature in implementations). I mean that it makes column values to be automatically initialized with an integer sequence, but doesn't guarantee uniqueness and strict consequentiality.

Still, I suppose that, unlike auto_increment/serial columns in MySQL/PostgreSQL, an ANSI-SQL-standard `generated always as identity` column doesn't allow its values to be set manually in INSERT or UPDATE (*only* automatically).

Comment: There is the concept of "identity" in standard ANSI SQL as well. You can define a column as `generated always as identity`

Comment: ANSI SQL also allows for `generated by default as identity` which is essentially the same as Postgres' `serial`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, so, values of ANSI identity fields can be changed manually afterwards, can't they?

Answer (score 1):

In a database table, every row should be unique, and you need to be able to identify a particular row uniquely.

A given table may have one or more columns which have unique values, so any of these columns can do the job. There may also be two or more columns which, while not unique of themselves, form a unique combination. That will also do.

Any column, or combination of columns, which can uniquely identify a row is called a **candidate key**. In principle, you can choose any key that you like, but you need to ensure that uniqueness is enduring. For example, in a small table of persons, the given name may be unique, but you run the risk of blowing that with the next additional person.

A **primary key** is the candidate key you nominate as your preferred
key. For example, a table of persons may have a number of unique attributes such as email address, mobile phone number and others. The primary key is the attribute you choose in preference to the others.

The following is *not* strictly required, but is good practice for a good Primary Key:

- A Primary Key shouldn’t change
- A Primary Key shouldn’t be recycled

For this reason, a Primary Key shouldn’t have any real meaning, so there should never be a reason to change or reuse it. As a result, the primary key is often an arbitrary code whose only real meaning is that it identifies the row. If the key is purely used for identification and has no other meaning, it is often referred to as a **Surrogate Key**.

You can put some effort into generating arbitrary codes. Sometimes they follow complex patterns which can be used to check their validity.

If you want to take a lazier approach, you can use a sequence number. Contrary to my previous advice, though, it does sort of have a meaning: it is strictly sequential, so you can learn which row was added *after* another, but not exactly when. However, that fact won’t change — it will not change in value, and will not be reused — so it’s still pretty stable.

An identity column is, in fact, a sequence number. It is auto-generated, and very useful if you want an arbitrary code for your primary key. Unfortunately it is relatively late to the very slow moving standards, so every DBMS had its own non-standard variation:

- MySQL calls it `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- SQLite calls it `AUTOINCREMENT`
- MSSQL calls it `IDENTITY()`
- MSACCESS calls it `AUTONUMBER`
- PostgreSQL calls it `SERIAL`

and each has its own quirks.

More recently, (2003, I believe) it has been added to the standards in the form of:

```
int generated by default as identity
```

but this has only just started to appear in PostgreSQL and Oracle. This use of `IDENTITY` behaves differently to Microsoft’s.

Answer (score 0):

primary key required unique number and primary key value can not be null that can get by identity and we not need to manually add at each new record which is added in table.

when record is failed to insert in table for some reason that time also identity is increase in sql server.

Comment: In which condition we use multiple identity key in a particular table?